# Windows 7: Is there a log of my c:\ accessed over a LAN from another computer?

Tags: windows-7, networking, administrator, remote-access

Windows7: Is there a log of accounts or IP addresses showing connections made to my computer's c:\ over a LAN connection using the format \\computername\C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a log of accounts showing connections made to my computer?

An event "**4624: An account was successfully logged on**" is added to the System Event Log.

The **Logon Type** will be **3** - Network (i.e. connection to shared folder on this computer from elsewhere on network).

The **Source Network Address** will be IP address of the computer where the user is physically present in most cases.

---

#### 4624: An account was successfully logged on

> Identifies the account that requested the logon - NOT the user who
>   just logged on.  Subject is usually Null or one of the Service
>   principals and not usually useful information.  See **New Logon** (later in this answer) for who
>   just logged on to the sytem.
>
> - Security ID
> - Account Name
> - Account Domain
> - Logon ID
>
> **Logon Information**:
>
> - Logon Type: See below
>
> Remaining logon information fields are new to Windows 10/2016
>
> - Restricted Admin Mode: Normally "-"."Yes" for incoming Remote Desktop Connections where the client specified /restrictedAdmin
> - Virtual Account: Normally "No". This will be Yes in the case of services configured to logon with a "Virtual Account".
> - Elevated Token: This has something to do with User Account Control but our research so far has not yielded consistent results.
>
> **Logon Type:**
>
> This is a valuable piece of information as it tells you HOW the user
>   just logged on:
>
> [image]
>
> **New Logon:**
>
> The user who just logged on is identified by the Account Name and
>   Account Domain.  You can determine whether the account is local or
>   domain by comparing the Account Domain to the computer name.  If they
>   match, the account is a local account on that system, otherwise a
>   domain account.
>
> - Security ID: the SID of the account
> - Account Name: Logon name of the account
> - Account Domain: Domain name of the account (pre-Win2k domain name)
> - Logon ID: a semi-unique (unique between reboots) number that identifies the logon session just initiated.  Any events logged
>     subsequently during this logon session will report the same Logon ID
>     through to the logoff event 4647 or 4634.
> - Logon GUID: Supposedly you should be able to correlate logon events on this computer with corresonding authentication events on the
>     domain controller using this GUID.  Such as linking 4624 on the member
>     computer to 4769 on the DC.  But the GUIDs do not match between logon
>     events on member computers and the authentication events on the domain
>     controller.
>
> **Process Information:**
>
> - Process ID is the process ID specified when the executable started as logged in 4688.
> - Process Name: identifies the program executable that processed the logon.  This is one of the trusted logon processes identified by
>     4611.
>
> **Network Information:**
>
> This section identifies WHERE the user was when he logged on.  Of
>   course if logon is initiated from the same computer this information
>   will either be blank or reflect the same local computers.
>
> - Workstation Name: the computer name of the computer where the user is physically present in most cases unless this logon was
>     intitiated by a server application acting on behalf of the user. 
>     Workstation may also not be filled in for some Kerberos logons since
>     the Kerberos protocol doesn't really care about the computer account
>     in the case of user logons and therefore lacks any field for carrying
>     workstation name in the ticket request message.
> - Source Network Address: the IP address of the computer where the user is physically present in most cases unless this logon was
>     intitiated by a server application acting on behalf of the user.  If
>     this logon is initiated locally the IP address will sometimes be
>     127.0.0.1 instead of the local computer's actual IP address.  This field is also blank sometimes because Microsoft says "Not every code
>     path in Windows Server 2003 is instrumented for IP address, so it's
>     not always filled out."
> - Source Port: identifies the source TCP port of the logon request which seems useless since with most protocols source ports are random.

Source [4624: An account was successfully logged on](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4624)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Windows Security Log Encyclopedia](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/Default.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I found the log in Event Viewer under Windows Logs under Security